# WPF: Is this behavior intended? PreviewLostKeyboardFocus and LostKeyboardFocus

Tags: c#, wpf, focus

I have a TextBox and I want to save the content, when the user leaves the TextBox. I planned to use PreviewLostKeyboardFocus, but it doesn't work as intended.

```
<TextBox PreviewLostKeyboardFocus="textBox2_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus" 
         LostKeyboardFocus="textBox2_LostKeyboardFocus" />
```

When I click on another control inside of the same application, I first get the PreviewLostKeyboardFocus event and then the LostKeyboardFocus event. But when I activate another application, the PreviewLostKeyboardFocus event simply doesn't happen. I only get LostKeyboardFocus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour.

The `PreviewLostKeyboardFocus` event is not raised when you switch to another application.

The main purpose of handling the event in the first place is to prevent the keyboard focus from changing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.previewlostkeyboardfocus(v=vs.110).aspx

And if the event was raised when you switch to another application, you would be able to prevent the keyboard focus from changing by handling this event and set the the `Handled` property of the `KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs` to `true` and this would effectively prevent the user from being able to focus any other element on the screen while running your application.

Comment: Can you tell me, where in the documentation it is stated that it does not raise when switching to another application? --- However, is there any mechanism or event I can use to find out if I loose the focus, before another application gets the focus. It's because I want to save the content of the TextBox to a file, so that another text editor can detect the changes. Eg Notepad++ only checks for updated files, when it receives the focus, and than it's to late for my to save it.

Comment: Please don't ask additional questions in the comments. Ask another question if you have another issue. But what about handling the LostKeyboardFocus event? Or you could handle the Deactivated event of the window or the Application: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.deactivated.aspx.